# How to use Multi SQL Database in Wordpress?

Tags: php, sql

It is my wp-config.php of Wordpress site.

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'bd_1');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'bd_1');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysitepass');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         '~+w/~cC@PI11/a5`xgC9N-e%|~CK2{^-`y?Ovl^8:2b~7hvZLXIw[Ux3g7`<uokK');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '^(?`vq-zMnu-~+7Z?kAjYGcLs5O8>ftEZ9H2b#9W^nX)YM^-n_CH$B|~LP3&v-q1');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'i4D]=Pzjkk_FSD$;|db%O<lM*KxB +4=Ny$%r1|]qC61q|t/<?Pbs~.O0_7&]}?M');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'fN74@4Zr{_QMio27b`M4V&f/B+W3A`X$U#t_~zVk6{c>~:Nij %f.a4I0VC>7&2a');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'IAsw4BOY8i]oP%JTpE9jrtY>[]H{p4<dp_c,9&G(do~O7EF]~L!pV`l,!e*X}<+<');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'dd6!djBuGsjFU fZ)wSY+dpQV4l9FMVx7qaYue^GRn=DK!|J|tw],6D?p qD62>p');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '{iuPzO-# Zf$8N{EWmL.nck=*?bp(GQF-dmfvp{ii9y4AVJkQ(#Df+RV8[/K*kdt');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '}K0^aDCmr%1L)zls6}#8q+YVHp?A$><I_!l~%XV5]oa@I2vo^*]+LFAyL<x:hZla');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the Codex.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
 */


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Now Tell me or replace following codes multi Database sql setup with read and write rules.

I want to connect her multi sql database under remote sql,
Because my database is too big.

Anyone help?

Comment: I would not post any AUTH keys or passwords publicly. Now you need to change them as soon as possible.

Comment: If you mean split your database content between multiple servers then I don't think WordPress is set up to do that, no. This is usually called 'sharding', and you'd need to work out how you are going to split the data (e.g. some tables on one server and some on another, or odd numbered rows on one server and even on another) and then add logic to handle this and to query both servers and recombine the results. Which may be extra tricky for searches or other queries that join several tables.

Comment: I think your best option is going to be to reduce the size of your database, e.g. work out if you can save less data, or e.g. if you have a large cache of transients in your wp-options table then move them into Redis instead; or get a bigger database server that can cope.